# python - read .txt file line by line

Tags: python, authentication, text-files

I am trying to read every line of my file which contains a list of usernames and than make a login system with it. I am trying to implement a basic login system which has usernames stored in a .txt file but my code doesn't work and I don't know why. I think that the problem is in my loop which checks for username.

Here is my code but it doesn't work it just prints fail all the time:

```
a = input('do you have an account y/n:')
 

if a == 'y':
    b = input('insert username:')

    file1 = open('file.txt', 'r')
    lines = file1.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        if not lines:
            pass 
            if line == b:
                print('pass')

    else:
        print('fail')

else:
    d = input('new username:')

    f = open("file.txt", "a")
    print(d, file=f)
    f.close()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `if not lines`?

Comment: Also your identation seems wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for line in lines:
    if not lines:
        pass 
        if line == b:
            print('pass')
```

If the file has any contents, `if not lines` will never be true.  And since `if line == b` is indented underneath that, it never gets executed.

Also, when you iterate over the lines in a file like that, `line` will have a newline character at the end, so `if line == b` would not be true anyway.  You'll have to strip off the newline character.

Try this instead:

```
for line in lines:
    if line.strip() == b:
        print('pass')
```